# Scenic restaurant overlooking Washington DC

Tags: sightseeing, restaurants, washington-dc

While planning a trip to Washington DC I was wondering whether there is some restaurant/bar from which you can overlook downtown at sunset/night.

An example in Atlanta would be the Sun Dial on top of the Westin hotel http://www.bing.com/search?cc=us&q=sun+dial+westin It is a revolving restaurant and bar, it is right in the middle of downtown and one can spend an evening at their bar for as low as 15-20$ per person.

I am sure that there are similar venues in Washington, just looking for nice places to spend an evening with a good view on the city. Ideally without having to spend 100+$. Any recommendations are highly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rotating+restaurant+washington+DC&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: [The tallest commercial building in Washington, DC is only 210 feet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_buildings_in_Washington,_D.C.), so you're unlikely to find anything nearly as impressive as the 723-foot Atlanta Westin.

Comment: If you just care about the view, go up to the top of the tower in the Old Post Office pavilion. There is a food court down below, but that's not why you go. Unlike the Washington Monument, you have big windows, and it is the only building on Pennsylvsnia Ave. that gets around the height restrictions.

Comment: Alternatively, check out Rosslyn for eats.

Comment: @AffableGeek The Old Post Office is closed for renovation/Trumpification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Washington has a [well-known height restriction](http://www.ncpc.gov/heightstudy/docs/Historical_Background_on_the_Height_of_Buildings_Act_%28draft%29.pdf) on its buildings; you'll find no places with panoramic views of downtown or the monumental core within the District.

The [rooftop scene](http://www.rooftoprestaurants.com/no-r-or-b-restaurant-Washington-DC.htm) is alive and well during the summer months, however. If you just want a view of the local neighborhood and perhaps the Washington Monument (which can be seen from a significant proportion of the area), there are dozens of restaurant, bar, and hotel rooftops in various neighborhoods: I have taken visitors for example to the [Kennedy Center Roof Terrace](http://www.kennedy-center.org/visitor/restaurants/) with views of Georgetown and the Potomac; [ADC](http://www.donovanhousehotel.com/) at the Donovan House Hotel on Logan Circle, [The Observatory](http://thegrahamgeorgetown.com/rooftop-bar-and-lounge/) at the Graham Hotel in Georgetown, and The Reef in Adams Morgan.

Probably the most popular venue-with-a-view is the unimaginatively named [P.O.V. Roof Terrace](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/whotels/property/dining/attraction_detail.html?propertyID=3279&attractionId=1004250496&language=en_US) atop the W Hotel at 15th and F St. NW near the White House. Visible from the windows are the section of the National Mall near Washington Monument, the White House, EEOB, and the Treasury Building. Long waits, loud voices, louche crowds, and luxury prices— but a lovely view.

[image: Promotional photo of P.O.V.]

For views of the Capitol Building, the best is Charlie Palmer Steakhouse, but their roof is [only open for private events](http://www.charliepalmer.com/charlie-palmer-steak-dc/private-events/). Across the river, the Sheraton Pentagon City has a rooftop pool with views of DC, the Pentagon, and Arlington National Cemetery, but no rooftop lounge or restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

Also across the river, the Doubletree in Crystal City Arlington has a revolving restaurant, the [SkyDome Lounge](http://doubletree3.hilton.com/en/hotels/virginia/doubletree-by-hilton-hotel-washington-dc-crystal-city-DCAAEDT/dining/skydome-lounge.html).